# How to show the images of friends who are using an app (code)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am developing an application on facebook. My application also has an registration page. When a new user enters into our application I want the application to show the images of all his friends who are using this app. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this problem requires that you use a Facebook Social Plugin.

You can't build your own registration form and show a user all his/her friends who are using your application before the user installs your application.  This is because, in order to get a list of the user's friends, you have to have a valid access token - as this isn't public information.

There are 2 different social plugins you can use.

1. The simple "login" button which looks like the Facebook login button. (documentation here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/)
2. A registration form, which uses their users' Facebook profile to pre-populate some fields.  You can also add fields to the form to get more information.  (documentation here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/)

Both of these show the user pictures of the friends that are already connected/installed, and this is pretty much the only way you can pull this off before the user authorizes your application.

**edit 5/20/2011**

After browsing around the FB Social Plugin docs, I found another Social Plugin that you could possibly use if you didn't want to use the Facebook Registration Social Plugin.  You can use the [Facepile](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/facepile/) Plugin.  This shows all the users' friends who have connected to your app, or page, or whatever you want..so you could build your own registration form and use this social plugin to achieve the friends photos result you were looking for.

Comment: I think he can make accept the facebook application before making the user "register" to its app (I guess register means filling some information into a form ..)

Comment: Yeah, but that seems less than ideal.  You've already passed the barrier that is the user install - the point I think that most users would be most interested in seeing.  Not to mention that using the registration plugin lets you consolidate this down into 1 step instead of 2, keeping conversion significantly higher.

Comment: +1 for the registration stuff which I was not aware of .. I guess it's the perfect solution for this problem ..

Comment: Hey Thanks  Dwarfy and Jim R both solutions are working good.But I m using the  solution given  by Jim R.Sir how to reduce the no images (show faces )For eg i  want to show only 5 friends

Comment: @Francis Dcunha - For the registration plugin, I don't know that you really can.  I don't see any documentation for the show_faces field.  You might be able to limit by specifying a smaller width for the box, and FB might (should, hopefully) in turn reduce the # of friends pictures it puts next to the register button.  I know that's what you can do with the like widget (Just make the width smaller).

Comment: I know this is an "old" question/answer, but I found new info - so I edited my answer with it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I see two solutions :

1. Simple, put a facebook like button "with faces" somewhere on your page, your users will then see the pictures of their friends who "liked" your page.

   The option for showing friends pictures is `show_faces="true"`
2. Second option, that is a bit more difficult :
   When a new user registers :

   1. Save it's Facebook ID in a DB.
   2. Get it's friend list using something like : `https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=...`
   3. Parse the returned JSON of its friends, and then compare with all the Facebook ID's you already have in your DB, you can find which friends are already in your systems, those are the friends you want to display, to get their pictures just use `<img src="http://graph.facebook.com/USER_FACEBOOK_ID/picture?type=small"></img>`

   See more about getting friends of a user [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) : read about the "friends" connection.

Comment: this doesn't show other users who have used the application, just the other users who have liked his Page on Facebook.  Zynga, and other game publishers, have a huge rift in the # of active users on their games and the # of people that like their Pages on Facebook.  This means that just because someone uses your app that doesn't necessarily mean they're going to like your Page.  In fact, they're probably less likely, as they might not want more "spam" in their news feed.

Answer (score 0):

the best way is to use [facepile](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/facepile/) you need to add data-app-id and don't add data-href because if you will add data-href then system will check that url not your app so the facepile
div will look like this:

```
<div class="fb-facepile" data-app-id="YOUR_APP_ID" data-max-rows="1" data-colorscheme="light" data-size="small" data-show-count="true"></div>
```